# How to determine if two phone numbers are the same?

Tags: android

If we have a phone number like `358541321` without a country code, sometimes when phone rings it says `(+56 - 358541321)` or  `+56358541321`.

How to detect whether the ringed number is first number?

**The number is not saved in phone memory in order to phone lookup.**

Answer (score 4):

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberUtils.html
provides a neat solution:

```
  import android.telephony.PhoneNumberUtils;
```

...

```
  String one = "+51 - 3245678";
  String two = "+513245678";
  boolean isSame = PhoneNumberUtils.compare(one, two);
```

Answer (score 1):

The usual solution to this problem is just to compare the last X (e.g. 7 or 8, depending on your country) digits of the number. In rare cases, this can lead to false positives, but usually it's a good approximation and it avoids the problem of different or missing country or area codes.

Comment: @Ata: It's what is usually done by phone applications that look up phone numbers in an address book. If you have a better idea, feel free to share it as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Java `regular expression` and String function `replaceAll` can do this easily.

this way,

```
    String one = "+51 - 3245678";
    String two = "+513245678";

    one = one.replaceAll("[^0-9]","");
    two = two.replaceAll("[^0-9]","");
    Toast.makeText(this, one+" -- "+two, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    if(one.equalsIgnoreCase(two))
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Both Are Equal", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Different", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```